# Is there a fast and nice method to detect a color of given pixel of running program?

Tags: python, colors, detection

So I'm trying to have my program detect a color of a pixel (with stated coordinates) and compare it with a HEX-given color. After it, it makes one of two moves. I want it to detect the color of pixel inside of a running program, so it is not image. Is there anyone who could've help me? What python library do I need for that?

I tried installing win32api and ctypes in pycharm but those seem outdated or not working.

Comment: The question isn't very clear for me, but I assume that you can try making a screenshot and working with it. How to make a screenshot with python is well-googleable.

Comment: The case is that taking a screenshot and then detecting the color would be much too slow. I am looking for a way of doing this, let's say, constantly